# MT5210 Native linking failed - Cannot build xamarin.ios (forms) app

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

**EDIT (22/06-21)**: I went thru all my nugets one by one and found that the extra mtouch args. comes from the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS nugets. Someone over there has made the lib. so that it append some global mtouch flags. (the current stable version appends "-ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz")
Since it dont seem to help to open an issue over there i must somehow make my lib. work with those flags. *great...*

I have a weird problem with building a ios forms app.

We have made a dll of a native library (openCV2) with some functions we need.

we have made a PoC that builds and runs just fine, but when we take it to the "real" app it cant build.

right before the build fails i see in the log:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.iOS/xxxx/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.2-14.6/response-file.rsp -v -v -v -v --gcc_flags=-ObjC
```

while on the PoC app the same line is:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.iOS/xxxx/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.2-14.6/response-file.rsp
```

i know the "-v -v -v -v" is from my additional mtouch args. but no where (that i can find) is the gcc_flags set and i cant find a way to remove it.

what i have tried with no luck:

- linking Foundation framework in the additional mtouch args. linking
- Foundation framework in the LinkWithAttribues.cs file in the binding
- project none, sdk-only and all linking. looked at diffrenses in the
- project files made all the changes i can think of in the LinkWith
- file eg. linker flags, smart linking c++ and the like. tried with and
- w/o this linker flag `L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/ -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Wl,-rpath -Wl,@executable_path/Frameworks`
- made sure the code in the implementation and PoC is 100% the same
- made the iOS build options 100% the same in project and PoC
- installed the xamarin.swift nuget
- tried both 4.8 and 5.0 xamarin forms

im running

- vs for mac 8.10 (for binding project)
- vs2019 16.10.1 (for app building)
- xamarin.ios 14.19 on both

does anyone have a idea on what is going wrong here?

Im at the end of my rope, any help or ideas on where to look would be greatly appricieted.

here is the complete "failing" build log:

```
     1>  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/appteam/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.iOS/xxx/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.2-14.6/response-file.rsp -v -v -v -v --gcc_flags=-ObjC 
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): warning : Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): warning : Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): warning : Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftos'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility50'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAccelerate'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMIDI'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Foundation):Foundation.DataProtocol.copyBytes(to: Swift.UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) -> Swift.Int. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Foundation.__DataStorage.init(bytes: Swift.UnsafeRawPointer?, length: Swift.Int) -> Foundation.__DataStorage. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for Foundation.__DataStorage. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for Foundation.Data.RangeReference. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Foundation.Data._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSData. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: static Foundation.Data._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(__C.NSData?) -> Foundation.Data. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol conformance descriptor for Foundation.Data : Foundation.DataProtocol in Foundation. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata for Foundation.Data. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: associated type descriptor for Swift.Sequence.Element. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: associated type descriptor for Swift.IteratorProtocol.Element. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: associated type descriptor for Swift.Sequence.Iterator. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: associated type descriptor for Swift.RawRepresentable.RawValue. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Foundation):Swift.Dictionary._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSDictionary. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Hashable._rawHashValue(seed: Swift.Int) -> Swift.Int. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Hashable.hash(into: inout Swift.Hasher) -> (). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Hashable.hashValue.getter : Swift.Int. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.Hashable. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: base conformance descriptor for Swift.Hashable: Swift.Equatable. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for static Swift.Equatable.== infix(A, A) -> Swift.Bool. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.Equatable. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Foundation):Swift.String._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSString. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: static (extension in Foundation):Swift.String._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(__C.NSString?) -> Swift.String. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Swift.String.hash(into: inout Swift.Hasher) -> (). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Swift.String.write<A where A: Swift.TextOutputStream>(to: inout A) -> (). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata for Swift.String. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol witness table for Swift.String : Swift.Hashable in Swift. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Sequence.makeIterator() -> A.Iterator. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Sequence._copyContents(initializing: Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<A.Element>) -> (A.Iterator, Swift.Int). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Sequence.underestimatedCount.getter : Swift.Int. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Sequence._copyToContiguousArray() -> Swift.ContiguousArray<A.Element>. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Sequence._customContainsEquatableElement(A.Element) -> Swift.Bool?. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.Sequence.withContiguousStorageIfAvailable<A>((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<A.Element>) throws -> A1) throws -> A1?. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: associated conformance descriptor for Swift.Sequence.Swift.Sequence.Iterator: Swift.IteratorProtocol. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.Sequence. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Swift):Swift.Sequence.withContiguousStorageIfAvailable<A>((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<A.Element>) throws -> A1) throws -> A1?. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.RawRepresentable.rawValue.getter : A.RawValue. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.RawRepresentable.init(rawValue: A.RawValue) -> A?. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.RawRepresentable. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Foundation):Swift.Array._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSArray. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: static (extension in Foundation):Swift.Array._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(__C.NSArray?) -> [A]. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: static Swift.Array._allocateBufferUninitialized(minimumCapacity: Swift.Int) -> Swift._ArrayBuffer<A>. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Foundation):Swift.Double._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSNumber. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: static (extension in Foundation):Swift.Double._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(_: __C.NSNumber, result: inout Swift.Double?) -> (). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata for Swift.Double. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata for Swift.Float. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Swift.Int.hashValue.getter : Swift.Int. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata for Swift.Int. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol conformance descriptor for Swift.Int : Swift.BinaryInteger in Swift. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.IteratorProtocol.next() -> A.Element?. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.IteratorProtocol. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Swift):Swift.BinaryInteger.description.getter : Swift.String. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Swift._StringGuts.grow(Swift.Int) -> (). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for Swift._ArrayBuffer. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: protocol conformance descriptor for Swift._ArrayBuffer<A> : Swift._ArrayBufferProtocol in Swift. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Swift._CocoaArrayWrapper.endIndex.getter : Swift.Int. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: Swift._CocoaArrayWrapper.subscript.getter : (Swift.Int) -> Swift.AnyObject. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: static Swift._DictionaryStorage.allocate(capacity: Swift.Int) -> Swift._DictionaryStorage<A, B>. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for Swift._DictionaryStorage. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: (extension in Swift):Swift._ArrayBufferProtocol._outlinedMakeUniqueBuffer(bufferCount: Swift.Int) -> (). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
```

(... shortend ...)

```
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(380,3): error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
 ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: If it has any impact, i need to say im running Xamarin.iOS 14.20.0.3 not 14.19 as i say in the question.
And if anyone knows where the "extra" --gcc_flags=-ObjC  flag comes from, its the only thing i can see that is different from the working PoC app. Its not set as a additional mtouch arg or set in the project file.

Comment: Have you poked around in the `csproj` file to look for those 'extra' --gcc_flags settings? Or have you just looked inside the Visual Studio UI?

Comment: Are you testing on simulator or real device? Could you post some images of your iOS project properties?

Comment: @Bijington yep, checked the project files, and its not from there :(

Comment: @Shaw im am testing on a real device. and here is the ios project properties [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/6fsqnmpqUL)

Comment: Right click on iOS (Project from solution explorer) -> Options -> iOS Build -> Additional mtouch arguments -> --gcc_flags.....   check this is similar to your PoC code.

Comment: @Ranjit they are (appart from the app name) the same. no only args are -v -v -v -v

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check changing the Linker Behavior to "Link Framework SDKs only" : [image]

Comment: Yes, sadly still same error. i have for good measure tried with "Don't" and "all" with the same result.